# Applovin Interstitials Not Coming Up Every Time, Only Sparingly

Tags: ios, ads, chartboost, applovin

So I set up Applovin SDK in my app and Applovin ads only come up sparingly.  All of my other apps with Applovin installed have the ads coming up accordingly.  Anyone heard of this kind of error?

**Here is what I have in the Appdelegate:**

```
 [ALSdk initializeSdk];

     Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
    cb.appId = @"TAKEN OUT";
    cb.appSignature = @"TAKEN OUT";
    // Required for use of delegate methods. See "Advanced Topics" section below.
    cb.delegate = self;
    [cb startSession];
    [cb cacheMoreApps];
    [cb showInterstitial];

//AppLovin Interstitial Ad

    if (self.theTimer == nil)
    {
       self.theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1000 target:self selector:@selector(countdownTracker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//Repeat to yes
    }


}
-(void)didCloseInterstitial:(NSString *)location
{
    [ALInterstitialAd showOver:self.window];

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

    if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {

    }

    NSString *valueToSave = @"yes";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
- (void)stopTimer
{
    if (self.theTimer != nil)
    {
        [self.theTimer invalidate];
        self.theTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record, I have it coming up after Chartboost interstitial.

Comment: Just wondering, what does countdownTracker do?

Comment: I have no idea, my dev advised me to put that in, could that be the culprit?

Comment: Would I have to remove the NSTimer for this to be resolved?